# PHP array only showing last sql result

Tags: php, arrays

Hello i am hoping someone can help me, when i use print_r all only get the last result from the mysqli query, my code is below.

```
//Fetch data from sql results
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()){
//Put results in a array
$page_query=array($row['name']=>$row['system']);
}
}
```

Comment: In you case `$page_query` isn't an array, it can hold just one value

Answer (score 5):

you are overwriting your `$page_query` everytime in loop, change to:

```
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()){
//Put results in a array
  $page_query[] =array($row['name']=>$row['system']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it to the array - not replace the entire variable with what you have in that row.

```
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc())
{
    //Put results in a array
    $page_query[]=array($row['name']=>$row['system']);
}
```

The short syntax for the function you are looking [Array_push](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) is simply to pop a set of empty square brackets behind the variable and then say `=something;`. This appends another element to the end of the array. This function will increment the index numerically.

Answer (score 0):

because every time inside while you reinitialize $page_query so you should push them inside array to collect. use `array_push()`